# kubectl not able to pull the image from private repository

Tags: docker, kubernetes, nexus, kubectl, kubeadm

I am running kubeadm alpha version to set up my kubernates cluster. 
From kubernates , I am trying to pull docker images which is hosted in nexus repository. 
When ever I am trying to create a pods , It is giving  "ImagePullBackOff" every time. Can anybody help me on this ?

Detail for this are present in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/41536

Pod definition :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
  labels:
    name: test
spec:
  containers:
    - image: 123.456.789.0:9595/test
      name: test
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8443
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: my-secret
```

Comment: Could you please post your Pod definition too?

Comment: Pod definition has added

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to [refer to the secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/#referring-to-an-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod) you have just created from the Pod definition.

When you create the secret with `kubectl create secret docker-registry my-secret --docker-server=123.456.789.0 ...` the server must exactly match what's in your Pod definition - **including the port number** (and if it's a secure one then it also must match up with the docker command line in systemd).

Also, the secret must be in the **same namespace** where you are creating your Pod, but that seems to be in order.

Comment: I have added imagePullSecrets into the pod definition .

Comment: Port numbers match up?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't have  access to the PC for now. I'll update the pod configuration ASAP.

Comment: Now, the pod definition has added. Could you please help me to figure out the error ?

Comment: In the kubernetes issue linked you are quoting your command as `kubectl create secret docker-registry my-secret --docker-server=123.456.789.0 --docker-username=admin --docker-password=XXXX --docker-email=test@xyz.com` . Have you fixed it since to say `kubectl create secret docker-registry my-secret --docker-server=123.456.789.09:9595 --docker-username=admin --docker-password=XXXX --docker-email=test@xyz.com` (note the port number)?

Comment: Can you increase kubelet log level to 4 (`--v=4`) and post parts of the log (`journalctl -u kubelet`)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135872/discussion-between-sitakant-and-janos-lenart).

Comment: Thanks for the "same namespace" - that was the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I received similar error while launching containers from the amazon ECR  registry. The issue was that I didn;t mention the exact "Image URI" location in deployment file.

Comment: Thats obvious ! If image URI is wrong , you will this error .