# Deploying Node.js apps with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I was trying to deploy a very basic Express app, a small server listening on 8080 on a EC2 server (Ubuntu 16.04) [following this tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/). On that server, it was created a Kubernetes cluster through kops 1.8.0.
After that, I created a Dockerfile like the following:

```
FROM node:carbon

ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
ENV PATH=$PATH:/home/node/.npm-global/bin

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
# At the end, set the user to use when running this image
USER node
```

After that, I built the image with `docker build -t ccastelli/stupid_server:test1`, I specified my credentials with `docker login -u ccastelli`, I copied the imaged ID from `docker images`, tagged it `docker tag c549618dcd86 org/test:first_try` and pushed with `docker push org/test` on a private repository in [cloud.docker.com.](http://cloud.docker.com)

After that I created a cluster secret with `kubectl create secret docker-registry ccastelli-regcred --docker-server=docker.com --docker-username=ccastelli --docker-password='pass' --docker-email=myemail@gmail.com`

After that I created a deployment file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: stupid-server-deployment
 spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: stupid-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: stupid-server
        image: org/test:first_try
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080 
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: ccastelli-regcred
```

I see from `kubectl get pods` that the image transitioned from `ErrPullImage` to `ImagePullBackOff` and it's not ready. Anyway the docker container was working on the client instance but not in the cluster. At this point, I'm a bit lost. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Edit: message error:

> Failed to pull image "org/test:first_try": rpc error: code =
>   Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: repository pycomio/test not
>   found: does not exist or no pull access

Comment: Do you host your docker private repository? If so, can the k8s cluster 1. resolve the domain properly and 2. can reach the port?

Comment: the private repo is on cloud.docker.com, I've added the error I get from the dashboard.

Comment: Try updating your secret to `--docker-server=https://cloud.docker.com` or your container `image: cloud.docker.com/org/test` or both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your --docker-server should be `index.docker.io`

```
DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER=https://index.docker.io/v1/
DOCKER_USER=Type your dockerhub username, same as when you `docker login`
DOCKER_EMAIL=Type your dockerhub email, same as when you `docker login`
DOCKER_PASSWORD=Type your dockerhub pw, same as when you `docker login`

kubectl create secret docker-registry myregistrykey \
  --docker-server=$DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER \
  --docker-username=$DOCKER_USER \
  --docker-password=$DOCKER_PASSWORD \
  --docker-email=$DOCKER_EMAIL
```

Comment: Thanks you're right, I've also found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267164/kubectl-not-able-to-pull-the-image-from-private-repository